# Pycharm doesn't recognize existing cone env

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

I have two env on my mac. One for 2.7 and one for 3.5. In pycharm when I try to create a new project, I'm not able to select correct environment. I am only given the option to create condo env, VM and local add.

I'm using PyCharm community edition 2016.1.3

Comment: Where are your envs located? You could setup them in "Add Local"

Comment: It turned out to be an issue with env. It didn't have the correct packages installed.